# How to remove redundant www subdomain in a shell script (sed/awk/etc)?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, zsh

I need to remove redundant "www." prefix in an ever-growing HUGE list of domains. Here's the sample:

```
# Type 1
domain1.tld
# Type 2
domain2.tld
www.domain2.tld
# Type 3
www.domain3.tld
sub.domain3.tld
foo.domain3.tld
www.sub.domain3.tld

# Expected
domain1.tld
domain2.tld
www.domain3.tld
sub.domain3.tld
foo.domain3.tld
```

The only thing that worked took forever since the list already contains more than 2 million lines.

```
cp 1.txt 2.txt
while read line; do
  sed "/www.$line/d" -i 2.txt
done < 1.txt
```

I'm using GNU utils and already fooled around with sed, awk, comm to no avail.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is it possible for, say `www.example.com`, to come before `example.com` in your input?

Comment: Did you try `sed 's/^www\.//' 1.txt`

Comment: That will remove valid entries. I did try, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

awk -F. '{
    if($1 != "www")
    {
        arr[$0]=1
    }
    else
    if(arr[substr($0,5)] == 1)
    {
        next
    }
    print
}' file
```

Check this out, although I am not sure how it would work in case of 2 million records.

UPDATE:

Explanation: The `awk` expression uses `.` as field separator, so suppose if line is `www.sub.domain3.tld`, `$1=www`, `$2=sub` …

It flags all lines which don't start with `www` by making them index in array `arr`. Suppose line is `sub.domain3.tld`, it will make it index in `arr[sub.domain3.tld]` and stores `e` in it. Now for every line starting with `www.`, it strips the `www.` and checks if the remaining line is stored in array, if yes, the line is not printed.

UPDATE:

This would produce the result independent of the order in which input is supplied, although the output is in jumbled sequence:

```
#! /bin/bash

awk -F. '{
    if ($1 != "www") {
        domains["www."$0]=0
        domains[$0]=1
    }
    else {
        if (domains[$0] == ""){ domains[$0]=1 }
    }
}
END {
    for (domain in domains) {
        if (domains[domain]) { print domain }
    }
}' file
```

This should produce the result in correct sequence independent of the order in which input is supplied:

```
#! /bin/bash

awk -F. '{
    if ($1 != "www") {
        redundant_domains["www."$0]=1
    }
    domains[NR]=$0
}
END {
    for (i=1 ; i < NR ; ++i) {
        if (!redundant_domains[domains[i]]) { print domains[i] }
    }
}' file
```

Comment: That did it, now I'm working in understanding the command. As for speed is done in less than a second (awk is insanely fast). Thank you so much!

Comment: @anonymous1184, although make sure, like if `www.sub.domain3.tld` occurs before `sub.domain3.tld` in the file, it won't remove `www.sub.domain3.tld`. So the way your `sed` code works, it checks the complete file everytime. As for the code I will edit the question to explain its working.

Comment: It's not really that awk is fast, so much as that `while read ...` is insanely slow.  `read` makes a system call for every single byte, while `awk` reads data in large chunks.

Comment: I figured that I needed to reverse-sort the input, did it via `<(sort -r file)`. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @anonymous1184, I have updated my answer to overcome the previous limitation, you can give it a try if needed.